# Вставка плагина в шаблон Joomla

Tags: joomla, php

Как в Joomla в шаблоне вывести (вставить) плагин. Модуль понятно

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position"  style="xhtml" />
```

А вот как плагин ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плагины не выводятся в шаблоне, они включаются для всего сайта из админки

Comment: Просто есть плагин для поиска по галереи. Я его включил, а вот как вывести поиск на страницу ???

Comment: нужно либо качать для галереи модуль поиска, или, что более вероятно, надо поставить стандартный joom-ловский поиск, сами плагины в шаблон не прописываются

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял !

Answer (score 0):

1. Вставить позицию модуля: `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position" style="xhtml" />`
2. Поместить в позицию модуль HTML-код
3. Включить в настройках модуля "Обрабатывать плагинами"
4. Вставить плагин в модуль